# How to get startsWith function to produce the character instead of the Boolean in R?

Tags: r, startswith, data-management

As the default, the `startsWith` function will produce a Boolean output:

```
x1 <- c("Foobar", "bla bla", "something", "another", "blu", "brown",
        "blau blüht der Enzian")

startsWith(x1, "b")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

How can one use it to get the actual names of the words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this we can use `grep` which have the `value` argument which by default is `FALSE`

```
grep("^b", x1, value = TRUE)
```

Or use the logical vector to subset

```
x1[startsWith(x1, "b")]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_subset` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_subset(x1, '^b')
#[1] "bla bla"    "blu"  "brown" "blau blüht der Enzian"
```